# What are practical use case of Positional only arguments and Keyword only arguments in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python has support for postional only and keyword only arguments

1. Positional only arguments

   ```
   def postional_only_func(a,b,/):
       ...
   ```
2. Keyword only arguments

   ```
   def keyword_only_func(*,a,b):
       ...
   ```

But, what are its practical use case when writing a function? Is it just to make code more readable?

Comment: As opposed to what third option/other alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these features were added to make writing certain functions easier. IF you want to read the full rational and motivation, you should read the corresponding PEPs:

1. [PEP 570 – Python Positional-Only Parameters](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/)
2. [PEP 3102 – Keyword-Only Arguments](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/)

For positional only, here are concrete examples for use-cases, using examples from the built-in functions:

> There are functions with other interesting semantics:
>
> - `range()`, an overloaded function, accepts an optional parameter to the left of its required parameter. [[4]](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/#range)
> - `dict()`, whose mapping/iterator parameter is optional and semantically must be positional-only. Any externally visible name for
>   this parameter would occlude that name going into the **kwarg keyword
>   variadic parameter dict. [[3]](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/#dict)
>
> One can emulate these semantics in Python code by accepting (*args,
> **kwargs) and parsing the arguments manually. However, this results in a disconnect between the function definition and what the function
> contractually accepts. The function definition does not match the
> logic of the argument handling.

And for keyword-only arguments it says the following regarding motivation:

> There are often cases where it is desirable for a function to take a
> variable number of arguments. The Python language supports this using
> the ‘varargs’ syntax (*name), which specifies that any ‘left over’
> arguments be passed into the varargs parameter as a tuple.
>
> One limitation on this is that currently, all of the regular argument
> slots must be filled before the vararg slot can be.
>
> This is not always desirable. One can easily envision a function which
> takes a variable number of arguments, but also takes one or more
> ‘options’ in the form of keyword arguments. Currently, the only way to
> do this is to define both a varargs argument, and a ‘keywords’
> argument (**kwargs), and then manually extract the desired keywords
> from the dictionary.